# Alterar bgcolor de acordo com a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Por enquanto não possuo muitos conhecimentos em JS e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida...

Preciso alterar o bgcolor de acordo com a class 'active'.
Por exemplo: "se a class 'active' estiver junto com 'banner-bg-1', a cor do body será 'orange'"

Segue o código de exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/79kzvnnu/13/

Comment: Você pode usar o evento `slid.bs.carousel` ao invés de `slide.bs.carousel`

Comment: Pelo que vi o .active fica "pulando" do banner-bg-1 para o banner-bg-2, mas vc quer que só no banner-bg-1 o background fique orange?

Comment: Uma coisa tão simples.... Não me apercebi desse detalhe. Agradeço aos comentários e a disposição de todos!
Seguindo o conselho do Valdeir, deu tudo certo!
Só substituir o 'slide.bs.carousel' por 'slid.bs.carousel' e deu certo!
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez você possa fazer dessa forma, em vez de verificar a classe ativa no elemento, vc pode pegar diretamente pelo evento de slide qual elemento que está ativo, e setando um data-attribute no html vc pode determinar qual cor é referente a cada item. dessa forma você não precisa mudar seu javascript a cada cor diferente, só seta o `data-bg` no html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //seta fundo referente a ao item active por default.
  trocaFundo("orange");

  $('#banner').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(ev) {
    $('body').addClass('animating');
    trocaFundo(ev.relatedTarget.dataset.bg);
  });

  function trocaFundo(color) {
    $('body').css({
      background: color
    });

  }
});
```

```css
body.animating {
  background: "orange";
  transition: background .7s ease-out;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 250px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="col-md-8 carousel slide" id="banner" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item banner-bg-1 active" data-bg="orange">
      <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-5">
        <div class="banner-texto">
          <h1>orange/laranja</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item banner-bg-2" data-bg="gray">
      <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-5">
        <div class="banner-text">
          <h1>grey/cinza</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="0" class="banner-li-1 active"></li>
      <li data-target="#banner" data-slide-to="1" class="banner-li-2"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uau Israel, simplesmente sensacional sua solução!
O código ficou até mais simples e semântico de se entender.
Preciso estudar mais JS hahaha
Obrigado, abraços!

Comment: Opa, obrigado amigo! Estamos aqui pra ajudar. Bons estudos!

Answer (score 0):

O evento `slid.bs.carousel` ocorre depois de o slide ficar ativo.

```
$('#banner').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
    mudaBG();
});
```